# 'alter table 'A' add column' that auto increment string value in SQL according to different column values

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm doing a project in Spring Boot and there have table named `master_file` and it has below columns.

| file_name | data_set_tag | file_type | deleted_status | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Values for **deleted_status = DELETED, NOT_DELETED**

Values for **file_type = FINANCE, HR, IS**

There are 2 points I need to achieve.

1. according to the particular file type, deleted_status = NOT_DELETED and for a particular year, need to set the value for data_set_tag with increment like *DATA-SET 1, DATA-SET 2* in file insert.

Expected result :

| file_name | data_set_tag | file_type | deleted_status | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| finance | DATA-SET 1 | FINANCE | NOT_DELETED | 2020 |
| finance quart | DATA-SET 2 | FINANCE | NOT_DELETED | 2020 |
| hr | DATA-SET 1 | HR | NOT_DELETED | 2020 |
| hr monthly | DATA-SET 2 | HR | NOT_DELETED | 2020 |
| finance quart | DATA-SET 3 | FINANCE | NOT_DELETED | 2020 |

2. When file is deleted and then insert a particular file type, data_set_tag value need to increment according to the deleted_Status = NOT_DELETED

Expected result :

| file_name | data_set_tag | file_type | deleted_status | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| finance | DATA-SET 1 | FINANCE | NOT_DELETED | 2020 |
| finance quart | DATA-SET 2 | FINANCE | NOT_DELETED | 2020 |
| hr | DATA-SET 1 | HR | NOT_DELETED | 2020 |
| hr monthly | DATA-SET 2 | HR | DELETED | 2020 |
| finance quart | DATA-SET 3 | FINANCE | DELETED | 2020 |
| finance report 1 | DATA-SET 3 | FINANCE | NOT_DELETED | 2020 |
| hr monthly | DATA-SET 2 | HR | NOT_DELETED | 2020 |

I tried add a new column to table and using get a `count` of each file_type which are NOT_DELETED in particular year and set that in data_set_tag as `DATA-SET count` to the  when insert file.

```
alter table master_file
    add data_set_tag varchar(20) not null;

FileEntity fileEntity = new FileEntity();
Integer fileCount = fileRepository.countByYearAndDeletedStatusAndAppealType(year,'NOT_DELETED', appealType );
fileEntity.setExamYear( examYear );
fileEntity.setFileName(originalFileName);
fileEntity.setDataSetTag( "DATA-SET " +  fileCount+1 );
fileEntity.setAppealType( appealType );
fileRepository.save(fileEntity);
```

**Is there a way to do this in Database column definition level at alter table add column?  Or is above way the best way to do this?**

I found questions related to this in [how-do-i-add-string-with-auto-increment-value-in-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170950/how-do-i-add-string-with-auto-increment-value-in-sql-server) , [auto-incrementing-a-number-that-is-part-of-a-string-value-in-a-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060725/auto-incrementing-a-number-that-is-part-of-a-string-value-in-a-sql-server-databa?noredirect=1&lq=1), [need-to-auto-increment-string-in-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969020/need-to-auto-increment-string-in-sql-server-2012) here but both do this in DB creation. I want this in Column creation since this table is already created.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to study triggers and stored procedures that can execute code inside database.

Comment: Trigger BEFORE INSERT can solve this task easily.

Comment: @nazim , Akina Thank you very much for your inputs. So what is the best way in performance wise? The way I do it or use a trigger?